# How to parse time factor regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the regular expression `([1-9]|1[0-2]|0[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) (AM|PM|am|pm)` for time factor. e.g. HH:MM pm.

Now I have to use this regular expression.

Sample code:

```
if(currentVal.match(/([1-9]|1[0-2]|0[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) (AM|PM|am|pm)/g) != currentVal) {
    alert("Invalid time.");
}                         

var parts = currentVal.split(" ");


var parts = currentVal.split(":");
parts[0] = parseInt(parts[0]);
parts[1] = parseInt(parts[1]);

if(parts[0] == 12) {
    parts[0] = 0;
}
if(parts[1].toLowerCase() == 'pm') {
    parts[0] += 12;
}
```

Here, my mistake is `parseInt(parts[1])`; because regular expression have ":" and "space" and  "(AM|PM|am|pm)" so it is not converting `parts[1]` in lower case.

Can anyone help me to use this regular expression?

Comment: You do not parse regular expressions, you use regular expression to parse strings.

Comment: `match` returns an array.  Why are you comparing your `currentValue` *string* to the *array* returned by `match`?  Perhaps you should be using the [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) function of the regex?

Comment: Also, you can shorten your regex to `/^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9]) (am|pm)/ig`

Comment: And finally, you need to add a word boundary (\b) or start-of-string (^) to the start of your regex or else "14:00 pm" will match because it contains  the valid match "4:00 pm".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the misuse of language pointed out by others, instead of this...

```
var parts = currentVal.split(" ");
var parts = currentVal.split(":");
```

...use another regex to split by spaces *and* colons:

```
var parts = currentVal.split(/[ :]/);
```

And then of course the `'pm'` will be stored in `parts[2]`.